# How to return data from selection in GetSelectName dialog in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I put together some VBA code designed to return information from a single selected Outlook contact. It returns the wrong person's information.

It seems to choose a contact relatively close in alphabetical order (first name), but never the correct one.

Choosing the first person in the list consistently returns the information for the last person.  I had others run it and they get the same issue. Outlook, Office and Excel Object Libraries are up to date (16.0).

```vb
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outDialog As SelectNamesDialog
Dim myAddrList As AddressList
Dim myAddrEntry As AddressEntry
Dim AliasName As String

Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set outDialog = outApp.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
Set myAddrList = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists("Contacts")

With outDialog
    .AllowMultipleSelection = False
    .InitialAddressList = myAddrList
    .ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = True
    If .Display Then
        AliasName = outDialog.Recipients.Item(1).Name
        Set myAddrEntry = myAddrList.AddressEntries(AliasName)
        Range("F3").Value = myAddrEntry.GetContact.FirstName
        Range("G3").Value = myAddrEntry.GetContact.LastName
        Range("M3").Value = myAddrEntry.GetContact.Email1Address
        Range("H3").Value = myAddrEntry.GetContact.CompanyName
        Range("I3").Value = myAddrEntry.GetContact.BusinessAddressStreet
        Range("J3").Value = myAddrEntry.GetContact.BusinessAddressCity
        Range("K3").Value = myAddrEntry.GetContact.BusinessAddressState
        Range("L3").Value = myAddrEntry.GetContact.BusinessAddressPostalCode
    End If
End With

Set outApp = Nothing
Set outDialog = Nothing
Set myAddrList = Nothing
Set myAddrEntry = Nothing
```

Comment: `AddressEntry.ID ` will return the unique id for a contact. Can't you use that in any way?

Comment: I tried using that but couldn't get anywhere with it.  I am swimming in the deep end of the pool on this one - I have never called outside of Excel for data before and trying to learn as I go.

Answer (score 0):

This Outlook code demonstrates how to connect the dialog selection to "Contacts".

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub GetAddresses()

Dim outDialog As SelectNamesDialog

Dim myAddrList As AddressList
Dim myAddrEntry As AddressEntry

Dim AliasName As String

Set outDialog = Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
Set myAddrList = Session.AddressLists("Contacts")

With outDialog

    .AllowMultipleSelection = False
    .InitialAddressList = myAddrList
    .ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = True
    
    If .Display Then
        AliasName = .Recipients(1).name
        Debug.Print "AliasName............: " & AliasName
        
        For Each myAddrEntry In myAddrList.AddressEntries
        
            If myAddrEntry.name = AliasName Then
                With myAddrEntry
                    Debug.Print ".Address.............: " & .Address
                    Debug.Print ".GetContact.FirstName: " & .GetContact.FirstName
                End With
                
                Exit For
            End If
            
        Next myAddrEntry
    
    End If

End With

End Sub
```